# Segmentation fault while implementing Bst

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was implementing BST, to achieve something in lines of getting parent of a searched node. I am getting segmentation fault core dumped.

My code

```
/**
 * Program to create BST and do basic functions on it
 */
using namespace std;

struct BstNode {
    int data;
    BstNode* left;
    BstNode* right;
};

BstNode* createNewNode(int data){
    BstNode* newNode = new BstNode();
    newNode->data=data;
    newNode->left=NULL;
    newNode->right=NULL;
    return newNode;
}

BstNode* insert(BstNode* root,int data){
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        root=createNewNode(data);
    }else if(root->data>=data)
    {
        root->left=insert(root->left,data);
    }else{
        root->right=insert(root->right,data);
    }
    return root;
}


int main()
{
    BstNode* root;
    root=insert(root,10);
    root=insert(root,5);
    root=insert(root,25);
    root=insert(root,45);
    BstNode* addr;
    BstNode* parentNode;
    addr=root;
    parentNode=root;
    return 0;
}
```

I am not able to find the reason for that. When I remove one of these 2 statements :

```
addr=root;
parentNode=root;
```

It starts working fine. Please help.

Comment: `BstNode* root` is uninitialised

Comment: `BstNode* root;` --> `BstNode* root = NULL;`

Comment: Accessing a variable before it has been initialized is undefined behavior.  Avoid undefined behavior; no good can come of it, and can only lead to tears, and wailing-and-gnashing of teeth.  And possibly nasal demons.

Comment: But when I will call insert function, that will initialise it. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @KashishGoyal Yes because the very first thing in `insert` is `if(root == NULL)`. At that point `root` is uninitialised.

Comment: Yes, I got the point. It is good to initialise variable before start using it. But why my code starts working fine when I remove these 2 lines

addr=root;
parentNode=root;

Comment: @KashishGoyal a uninitialized pointer variabel is *not* automatically set to `nullptr`. It has an indeterminate value and reading it is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). And with UB *any* behaviour is acceptable - you can no longer reason about what the code does or why. You *must* initialize the pointer before accessing it.

Comment: Once you have undefined behavior, *anything* can happen.  It's C++'s greatest strength, and greatest annoyance.  It can crash.  It can give the wrong results.  It can give the right results.  It can email your grandmother your browser history then format your hard drive.  It could **destroy the Earth**.

Comment: Ok. Thank you Eljay, John, Jesper

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function `createNewNode` can look much simpler

```
BstNode* createNewNode(int data){
    return new BstNode { data };
}
```

and you forgot to initialize initially the pointer root

```
BstNode* root;
```

There must be

```
BstNode* root = nullptr;
```